# useContext functionality not working in React for image preview

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am having two pages in my application FrontClient and BackClient, the functionality that I am aiming for here is that when a user selects a particular image from the BackClient that particaular image needs to be displayed on the FrontClient and for this I am using useContext. I am storing images in firebase storage and therefore in the BackClient I want to pass on the image URL to the FrontClient.

NoticeContext.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const NoticeContext = createContext();

export const NoticeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [activeImage, setActiveImage] = useState('');

  return (
    <NoticeContext.Provider value={{ activeImage, setActiveImage }}>
      {children}
    </NoticeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

FrontClient.js:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NoticeContext } from './NoticeContext';

const FrontClient = () => {
  const { activeImage } = useContext(NoticeContext);
  console.log(activeImage)

  return (
       ....
      {activeImage && <img src={activeImage} alt="Active Image" />}
      .....
  );
  
};
```

BackClient.js:

```
...
import { NoticeContext } from './NoticeContext';
...
const { setActiveImage } = useContext(NoticeContext);
...
const handleActiveButtonClick = (notice) => {
    setActiveImage(notice.url);

};
...
return(
....
<Button onClick={() => handleActiveButtonClick(notice)}>
  <CheckIcon />
</Button>
)
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NoticeProvider } from './NoticeContext';
import FrontClient from './FrontClient';
import BackClient from './BackClient';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
       <NoticeProvider>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<FrontClient />} />
        <Route path="/admin" element={<BackClient />} />
      </Routes>
      </NoticeProvider>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```